# Sinon fakeserver doesn't respond when API's are invoked from a callback of setTimeout

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, sinon

Like the title of this question says sinon fake server is not responding to the API/ajax calls made from a callback of setTimeOut.

Status.js

```
_checkStatus() {
    if (...) {
      ....
      }
    } else if (...) {
      ....
    } else {
      setTimeout(async () => {
        this.status = await services.getStatus();
        this._checkStatus();
      },100);
    }
  }
```

Status.test.js

```
    const API_STATUS = /\/status/;
    const cType = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' };
    const mocks = {};
    mocks.get = { code: 'ready' };
    const server = fakeServer.create();
    server.respondImmediately = true;
    server.respondWith(API_STATUS, [200, cType, JSON.stringify(mocks.get)]);
    el._checkStatus();

    setTimeout(function(done){
      expect(el.status).to.equal('ready');
      done();
    }
      ,500);
  });
```

When we execute this test it invokes the mocks that are defined in the repo folder but not picking up the fake server mock defined above. However if I move the getStatus() call outside the timeout then it works with fake server. Just an FYI that getStatus() invokes the status API call.

Comment: This is very weird. Are you able to make a minimal reproducible testcase, like with RunKit or a tiny repo? It could be any number of things that are outside what we see in the test.

Comment: Dint try with a tiny repo or RunKit. Will try that and let you know If I can reproduce it.